# How to publish data without MongoDB through subscriptions in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, ddp

Essentially, this is what I had in mind :

### Client

```
const Messages = new Mongo.Collection("messages");

Meteor.call("message", { room: "foo", message: "Hello world");
Meteor.subsribe("messages", "foo");

// elsewhere
const messages = Messages.find({ room: "foo" });
```

### Server

```
Meteor.methods({
  message: ({ room, message }) => {
    // 1. remove old messages in the room
    // 2. add new message to the room
  }
});

Meteor.publish("messages", function (room) {
   // 1. return message collection for room
});
```

The client, I assume, uses `minimongo`, which is fine, but the server does not have access to a MongoDB instance whatsoever.

What would be the implementation on the server?

Comment: This can be done following the complex `publish` example in the documentation, manually calling `this.added`, etc. But doesn't meteor complain if you try to start it without a mongo connection? Have you already overcome that problem somehow?

Comment: @ChristianFritz No, meteor does not complain about a lack of MongoDB. I do not recall what I did exactly, but everything deploys just fine locally.

Comment: what are you setting for `MONGO_URL`?

Comment: @ChristianFritz nothing. There are only two env variables : `PORT` and `ROOT_URL`. The app has been running non stop in production since last November without any complain (empty logs). I know I did something to prepare that app so MongoDB would not be a requirement, but I do not recall what. I've been working on many projects since then. The point is, I need to to add this feature :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, I think this can be achieved using the manual publication methods described in [the documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-publish). Something like this might work:

```js
// Server:

const rooms = {};

Meteor.publish('manualMessages', function(roomId) {
  check(roomId, String);
  rooms[roomId] = this;
  this.ready();
});

Meteor.methods({
  message: ({ roomId, message }) => {
    // 1. remove old messages in the room
    const room = rooms[roomId];
    if (!room) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('no room', 'that room does not exist');
    }
    room.removed('messages', roomId);
    // 2. add new message to the room
    room.added('messages', roomId, { message });
  }
});



// Client:
const Messages = new Mongo.Collection("messages");

Meteor.call("message", { room: "foo", message: "Hello world");
Meteor.subsribe("manualMessages", "foo");

// elsewhere
const messages = Messages.find({ room: "foo" });
```

One thing to verify is whether `this` in the `publish` function changes per client, in which case `rooms` should contain arrays, or whether it is the same object for all clients, as assumed here. But hopefully this point you in the right direction.